# Best practices for sharing a symfony application between unix host and vagrant client vm

Tags: symfony, vagrant, nfs

I am using Vagrant on my Ubuntu machine, which I provision using Ansible, to work on my Symfony 2 project.

I've tried to find the best setup for sharing my code between the host and client machine, but I keep having encountering troubles:

1. Cache and logs directories are not writable, even when the folders have 777 rights.
2. Loading the application via the browser is extremely slow.

I have solved the first with placing the cache and logs folder on /tmp/cache(logs) since this is just my development environment.

This leaves me with the question on how to properly set up the file sharing between host and client machine where you do not experience these extreme loading times.

Edit: I am using NFS to share the folder and it's contents

Comment: Changing AppKernel.php to write cache and log folders to /tmp should also improve loading times via the browser.

Comment: @fieg As mentioned in my question, I already replaced these locations. Do you have any other suggestions perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161425/why-is-my-symfony-2-0-site-running-slowly-on-vagrant-with-linux-host especially the link to http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html

Comment: @fieg thank you for this reference. I've read it and found that I've already tried many of those solutions, for example the usage of sshfs. But I would like to be able to just use the shared folder, and make it easy for linux, mac and windows host systems. Unfortunately there seems to be pros and cons for every possible way of sharing the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [NFS shares](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html)? This usually increases performance dramatically.

Comment: I forgot to add this to my question, i will add it now, but I am already using NFS.