# Mac OS + Syfmoyn2 + Apache + PHP-FPM slow dev mode

Tags: php, macos, apache

if switched from Vagrant (Ubuntu 14.04) to local install Stuff and now my Application is very slow in Dev mode (Vagrant Dev mode Total time: round about 3.000 ms, now i got 17.000ms)

I've install the same PHP and Apache Version

```
php --version
PHP 5.6.20 (cli) (built: Mar 31 2016 17:14:52) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans

apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 20 2016 20:03:19
```

I using mod_fastcgi and configure it like this:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/Users/me/work/symfony2/web/$1
```

I've try to disable XDebug, but the speed won't got up.

On the Mac is running El Capitan Version 10.11.4 and I install all packages with brew.

Comment: Install nginx+php-fpm+mysql on host system and look time. Maybe application slowely

Comment: Tried googling it? [link 1](http://jeremybarthe.com/2015/02/02/speed-up-vagrant-environment-symfony2/), [link 2](http://by-examples.net/2014/12/09/symfony2-on-vagrant.html), [link 3](https://www.dev-metal.com/links-fix-extremely-slow-symfony-inside-vagrant-box/), [link 4](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Symfony 2.0 site running slowly on Vagrant with Linux host?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161425/why-is-my-symfony-2-0-site-running-slowly-on-vagrant-with-linux-host)

Comment: No. I've switched from Vagrant to host system. Not the other way. Vagrant time was okay.